# Elastic wave in isotropic medium

Tags: waves, elasticity, differential-equations

The 2D elastic wave equation is given by:

$$ \begin{align} 
\rho \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} &= C_{11} \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + C_{44} \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2} + (C_{12} + C_{44}) \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x \partial y} \\
\rho \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial t^2} &= C_{11} \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial y^2} + C_{44} \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2} + (C_{12} + C_{44}) \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}
\end{align} $$

For an isotropic medium:

$$ \begin{align} 
C_{11} &= \lambda +2 \mu \\
C_{12} &= \lambda \\
C_{44} &= \mu
\end{align}$$

What is the solution of this isotropic wave equation? And will the result be spherical symmetric?

My understanding of the equation:

1. The first term of right part: describes the compressive wave + gives elliptical solution when gaussian pulse is applied.
2. The second term of right part: describes the shear wave + gives elliptical solution when gaussian pulse is applied.
3. The first and second term result in a spherical wave when added together.

Question: What is the contribution of the third term and can it be qualitatively be explained? Will it break the spherical symmetry?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/rdaileda/teach/s12/m3357/lectures/lecture_3_1_short.pdf

Comment: In that case, they present the wave equation with the out-of-plane displacement w: $$  
\rho \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial t^2} = C_{44} \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + C_{44} \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial y^2} $$ with displacement = [u,v,w]. I am wondering if you neglect the displacement out of the plane and only take into account displacemnt in the plane.

Comment: Not sure but I've never seen the elastic wave equation in 2D in the form presented in your question.

Comment: Here are several links where you can find it: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00682707/file/InTech-Modelling_seismic_wave_propagation_for_geophysical_imaging.pdf, http://rses.anu.edu.au/~nick/teachdoc/lecture3.pdf, http://www.math.chalmers.se/~larisa/www/Aposter_elastic.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the references, I was going to ask for them.